# Deriving a polynomial equation from a data set of 360 points using the Lagrange Method

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I have a data set of 360 points, where on the x-axis I have every day of the year. On the y-axis, I have a set of integer values of the same length. I want to use the Lagrange Method to derive a polynomial equation from the data set, however this means the polynomial would end up in the  359th degree -- a very large exponent. Would it make more sense to take a subset of these points to derive the equation? And if I did, would it still accomplish my goal?

Comment: Depends on your goal, to be blunt.

Comment: Basically, I have a data set of stock prices -- where x_n is a day of the year and y_n is that day's stock's closing price. I want to try and predict future price trends using the polynomial equation (whether or not this is actually smart to do, is off topic haha).

Comment: Usually high degree polynomial interpolation performs quite poorly. Most of the time you are better off retaining all the data except possibly the outliers and using low degree inexact interpolation (least squares or similar), or a non-polynomial interpolation if that's appropriate to the context.

Comment: I see. So you believe using least squares would be a better method for what I want to do?

Comment: @Ian Because of your comment, I looked up the downsides to the approach I wanted to take and will be using a different method to achieve my goal. Thank you.